# Rabin-Karp rolling hash

Tags: java, rabin-karp

In one of the Coursera videos the Rabin-Karp rolling hash (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) is shown as:

```
public static long getHash(String S)
{
    long H = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
        H = (H * 10 + S.charAt(i)) % 997;

    return H;
}
```

I think it's wrong. I think it should be :

```
public static long getHash(String S)
{
    long H = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
        H = (S.charAt(i) * (int)Math.pow(10, (S.length() - i - 1)) + H) % 997;

    return H;
}
```

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours cannot possibly be right because

```
(int)Math.pow(10, (S.length() - i - 1))
```

for any string longer than 11 characters results in Integer.MAX_VALUE, for the first length-11 or length-12 characters. For example, for a 20-character string, when `i == 0` in your loop, this is expression is

```
(int)Math.pow(10, (20-0-1))
```

10<sup>19</sup> does not fit in an `int`, so the result of the cast is `2147483647`

Comment: Why not? At each iteration the value of `H` is always in the range `0 - 996`.  You're right that it doesn't look quite like the Wikipedia description, but the only difference is that it processes the characters in the reverse sequence. a^0 is applied to the leftmost character, not the rightmost.